# How to read an on-line JSON database?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I need to read an on-line JSON database (here's the [link](https://quotes.instaforex.com/get_quotes.php?m=json&q=gold,silver))

```
    {
    "GOLD": {
        "symbol": "GOLD",
        "lasttime": 1378862415,
        "digits": 2,
        "change": "-0.09",
        "bid": "1364.15",
        "ask": "1364.75"
    },
    "SILVER": {
        "symbol": "SILVER",
        "lasttime": 1378862413,
        "digits": 3,
        "change": "-0.005",
        "bid": "22.945",
        "ask": "22.985"
    }
}
```

and I need to take the gold and silver values to my HTML page via jQuery, I wrote this but it doesn't work, but nothing appears in the HTML.

```
$.getJSON('https://quotes.instaforex.com/get_quotes.php?m=json&q=gold,silver', function (data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
    });
    $('<ul/>', {
        'class': 'my-new-list',
        html: items.join('')
    }).appendTo('body');
});
```

With the same code if I use this JSON it works:

```
   {
        "symbol": "GOLD",
        "lasttime": 1378862415,
        "digits": 2,
        "change": "-0.09",
        "bid": "1364.15",
        "ask": "1364.75"
    }
```

How I can tell to the script to read the right JSON with both: gold and silver, the one that you can find at the top-page link?

And I'd like to make something like [this](http://shop.prontogold.com/quotazioni/).

Comment: try alert on the keys and values to see if you get anything

Comment: Are you running your code from the quotes.instaforex.com? If not, it won't be possible, cross-domain calls are blocked. You'll have to find a database that provides the result in JSONP format.

Comment: @bfavaretto Or alternatively you can create a server-side proxy on your server. In PHP it'd just be something like `echo file_get_contents([URL HERE]);`. Then you load your script with normal JSON and JSONP is not necessary.

Comment: SORRY I DIDN'T UNDERSTAND... I'M USING THE SAME THAT I POSTED HERE...

Comment: @MIOII Posting in caps won't win you any points here.

Comment: sorry it was a mistake...! somebody can help me? please

Comment: @jasper it doesn't work...

Comment: @bfavaretto i linked this: getJSON('https://quotes.instaforex.com/get_quotes.php?m=json&q=gold,silver', function (data) so it's running from instaforex right?
i need to link instaforex to make the values update...understand?

Comment: It won't work because that's not *your* site, and the browser will block it. You have to use php as Jasper suggested.

Comment: ok but when i try to use a local copy of the JSON (testjson.php) the javascript it doesn't work, why? only if i use only the "gold" or only the "silver" it works... it's a 2d array? are two object? what's that? how i can make it work and to get the value that i need?

Comment: how exactly and explicitally can i fix my problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
// segnalato dove andare a cercare ora definisco gli oggetti    
$.getJSON('JSON-DOCUMENT.php', function(json) {
 var N°1 = json.VAR-N°1;
 var N°2 = json.VAR-N°2;
...ECC...

 var N°1 = SOME OPERATIONS IF YOU WANT
 var N°2 = SOME OPERATIONS IF YOU WANT
 // pubblico in DIV tramite funzione .text
  $("YOUR-DIV").text(+ goldAsk');

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

file_get_contents() is not needed here because he said "With the same code if I use this JSON it works:"

MIOII, you have answered your question already.

```
   {
        "symbol": "GOLD",
        "lasttime": 1378862415,
        "digits": 2,
        "change": "-0.09",
        "bid": "1364.15",
        "ask": "1364.75"
    }
```

is a part of something bigger...

```
 {
    "GOLD": {
        "symbol": "GOLD",
        "lasttime": 1378862415,
        "digits": 2,
        "change": "-0.09",
        "bid": "1364.15",
        "ask": "1364.75"
    },
    "SILVER": {
        "symbol": "SILVER",
        "lasttime": 1378862413,
        "digits": 3,
        "change": "-0.005",
        "bid": "22.945",
        "ask": "22.985"
    }
}
```

Look at this as multidimensional array:

```
JSON[
GOLD[symbol,lasttime...]
SILVER[]
sthelse[]
]
```

Your answer: loop JSON then again, loop its children

```
     $.getJSON('https://quotes.instaforex.com/get_quotes.php?m=json&q=gold,silver', function(JSON) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(JSON, function(JSONchildren, contentsOfJSONchildren) {
            //JSONchildren - GOLD, SILVER
            $.each(contentsOfJSONchildren, function(index, value) {
                //index - symbol,lasttime,digits...
                //value - value of index
                items.push('<li id="' + index + '">' + value + '</li>');
            });
        });
        $('<ul/>', {
            'class': 'my-new-list',
            html: items.join('')
        }).appendTo('body');

    });
```

Now format

```
items.push('<li id="' + index + '">' + value + '</li>');
```

as you need it